# Sum of contigous subsequences in an array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Given the following array:

```
tab = [80,12,14,5,70,9,26,30,8,12,16,15]
```

I want to compute the sum of all  possible sequences of size 4 as follow:

```
S1=80+12+14+5=111
S2=12+14+5+70 =101
S3=14+5+70+9 =98
....
```

I have implmented a short program on python to do this and its not efficient:

```
import numpy as np


tab= np.array([80,12,14,5,70,9,26,30,8,12,16,15])
tab_size=tab.size
n=tab_size
s=0
seq_len=5
for i in range (0,n-(seq_len-1),1):
    print("index i ",i)
    for k in range(i+1,(seq_len+i),1):
            print ("index k ", k)
            tab[i]=tab[i]+tab[k]
            s=s+1
print(s)         
tab
```

the result is as follow :

```
array([111, 101,  98, 110, 135,  73,  76,  66,  51,  12,  16,  15])
```

I notice that each element will participate in the sum operation 4 times which is not good.
do you have any efficient idea to do that?
I want to add that, the sequence size is not fixed, in this example is just 4.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want all permutations of length 4 in list : `for x in list(permutations(tab, 4)):print (sum(x))`

Comment: can you explain more concerning the permutations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to keep the cumulitive sum upto current index and subtract the cumulative sum 4 index back,

```
tab = [80,12,14,5,70,9,26,30,8,12,16,15]
cumulative_sum = [0]*(len(tab)+1)
ret = []
for i in xrange(len(tab)):
    cumulative_sum[i+1] = cumulative_sum[i] + tab[i]
    if i >= 3:
      ret.append(cumulative_sum[i+1] - cumulative_sum[i-3])
```

In place version(without the `cumulativeSum` list and storing that in `tab` instead),

```
tab = [0] + [80,12,14,5,70,9,26,30,8,12,16,15]
ret = []
for i in xrange(1, len(tab)):
    tab[i] += tab[i-1]
    if i >= 4:
      ret.append(tab[i] - tab[i-4])
```

It works because it keeps track of the cumulative sum upto every index. So for any index, the sum of the sequence of length `n` ending at that index can be found using `cumulativeSum[index] - cumulativeSum[index-n]`

Comment: Please can you explain more your idea and put the complete code?@Fallen

Answer (score 5):

- Once you calculated `S1`, you just need to add 70 and substract 80 to get `S2`.
- Once you calculated `S2`, you just need to add 9 and substract 12 to get `S3`.
- ...

This way, you'll avoid using each element 4 times.

Comment: works only with integer sums. With floating point you can have loss of precision. Works here!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Interesting point. I'm not sure how big this loss could be. I don't think it could always drift away in the same direction, since any `+x` will be compensated by `-x` 4 steps later.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
print [sum(item) for item in [tab[n:n+4] for n in range(0, len(tab))] if len(item) == 4]
# Result [111, 101, 98, 110, 135, 73, 76, 66, 51]
```

Answer (score 2):

Short solution using `sum` and `enumerate` functions:

```
tab = [80,12,14,5,70,9,26,30,8,12,16,15]
sums = [sum(tab[i:i+4]) for i, v in enumerate(tab) if i+4 <= len(tab)]

print(sums)
```

The output:

```
[111, 101, 98, 110, 135, 73, 76, 66, 51]
```

The last "4-items" *consequent* sequence to be summed up is `8,12,16,15`(gives `51`)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this approach:

```
tab = [80,12,14,5,70,9,26,30,8,12,16,15]

for i in range(len(tab) - 3):
    summation = sum(tab[i:i+4])
    print(summation)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use numpy

```
A=np.array([80, 12, 14, 5, 70, 9, 26, 30, 8, 12, 16, 15])
print reduce(lambda x,y: x + [sum(y)], np.array(zip(A,A[1:],A[2:],A[3:])).tolist(),[])
```

output

> [111, 101, 98, 110, 135, 73, 76, 66, 51]